# Splitting on two rows equation enclosed in square brackets inside align environment

Tags: equations, formatting, align

I've the following equation:

```
\begin{align}
\left[
1 - \frac{m \, t}{\sigma \, \sqrt{n}} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{m^2 \, t^2}{\sigma^2 \, n} + 
\frac{m \, t}{\sigma \, \sqrt{n}} - \frac{m^2 \, t^2}{\sigma^2 \, n} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{m^3 \, t^3}{\sigma^3 \, n^{3/2}} +
\frac{\mathbb{E} [X_1^2]}{2} \frac{t^2}{\sigma^2 \, n} -
\frac{\mathbb{E} [X_1^2]}{2} \frac{m \, t^3}{\sigma^3 \, n^{3/2}} +
\frac{\mathbb{E} [X_1^2]}{4} \frac{m^2 \, t^4}{\sigma^4 \, n^2} +
O \left( \frac{t^3}{n^{3/2}} \right)
\right]^n
\end{align}
```

I'd like to split it in by using `\\` for example, but I got an error:

```
\begin{align}
\left[
1 - \frac{m \, t}{\sigma \, \sqrt{n}} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{m^2 \, t^2}{\sigma^2 \, n} + 
\frac{m \, t}{\sigma \, \sqrt{n}} - \frac{m^2 \, t^2}{\sigma^2 \, n} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{m^3 \, t^3}{\sigma^3 \, n^{3/2}} +
\\
\frac{\mathbb{E} [X_1^2]}{2} \frac{t^2}{\sigma^2 \, n} -
\frac{\mathbb{E} [X_1^2]}{2} \frac{m \, t^3}{\sigma^3 \, n^{3/2}} +
\frac{\mathbb{E} [X_1^2]}{4} \frac{m^2 \, t^4}{\sigma^4 \, n^2} +
O \left( \frac{t^3}{n^{3/2}} \right)
\right]^n
\end{align}
```

---

EDIT

```
\begin{align}
...
&= \Bigg\{ \Bigg\{ 1 + m \, \frac{t}{\sigma \, \sqrt{n}} + \mathbb{E} [X_1^2] \, \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{t}{\sigma \, \sqrt{n}}\right)^2 + O\left[ \left( \frac{t}{\sigma \, \sqrt{n}} \right)^3 \right] \Bigg\}
\\
&\Bigg\{ 1 - \frac{m \, t}{\sigma \, \sqrt{n}} + \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{m \, t}{\sigma \, \sqrt{n}} \right)^2 + O\left[ \left( \frac{m \, t}{\sigma \, \sqrt{n}} \right)^3 \right] \Bigg\} \Bigg\}^n = \\
&=
\left[
1 - \frac{m \, t}{\sigma \, \sqrt{n}} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{m^2 \, t^2}{\sigma^2 \, n} + 
\frac{m \, t}{\sigma \, \sqrt{n}} - \frac{m^2 \, t^2}{\sigma^2 \, n} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{m^3 \, t^3}{\sigma^3 \, n^{3/2}} +
\frac{\mathbb{E} [X_1^2]}{2} \frac{t^2}{\sigma^2 \, n} -
\frac{\mathbb{E} [X_1^2]}{2} \frac{m \, t^3}{\sigma^3 \, n^{3/2}} +
\frac{\mathbb{E} [X_1^2]}{4} \frac{m^2 \, t^4}{\sigma^4 \, n^2} +
O \left( \frac{t^3}{n^{3/2}} \right)
\right]^n 
= \\
&= \left[
1 - \cancel{\frac{m \, t}{\sigma \, \sqrt{n}}} +
\frac{1}{2} \frac{m^2 \, t^2}{\sigma^2 \, n} + 
\cancel{\frac{m \, t}{\sigma \, \sqrt{n}}} -
\frac{m^2 \, t^2}{\sigma^2 \, n} +
\frac{\mathbb{E} [X_1^2]}{2} \frac{t^2}{\sigma^2 \, n} +
O \left( \frac{t^3}{n^{3/2}} \right)
\right]^n = \\
&=
\left[
1 - \frac{1}{2} \frac{m^2 \, t^2}{\sigma^2 \, n} +
\frac{\mathbb{E} [X_1^2]}{2} \frac{t^2}{\sigma^2 \, n} +
O \left( \frac{t^3}{n^{3/2}} \right)
\right]^n = \\
&=
\left[
1 +
\left( \mathbb{E} [X_1^2] - m^2 \right)
\, \frac{t^2}{2 \, \sigma^2 \, n} +
O \left( \frac{t^3}{n^{3/2}} \right)
\right]^n = 
&& \text{(g)} \\
&=
\left[
1 + \sigma^2 \frac{t^2}{2 \, \sigma^2 \, n} + O \left( \frac{t^3}{n^{3/2}} \right)
\right]^n = \\
&=
\left[ 1 + \frac{t^2}{2 \, n} + O \left( \frac{t^3}{n^{3/2}} \right) \right]^n
\end{align}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

For this `align` environment is not right choice. Instead it you should use `alined` inside some math environment (for example `equation` or `\[ ... \]`) or as I did in the following MWE: use the `multiline` environment defined in the `mathtools` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, mathtools}


\begin{document}
    \[
\left[
    \begin{multlined}
1 - \frac{m \, t}{\sigma \, \sqrt{n}} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{m^2 \, t^2}{\sigma^2 \, n} +
\frac{m \, t}{\sigma \, \sqrt{n}} - \frac{m^2 \, t^2}{\sigma^2 \, n} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{m^3 \, t^3}{\sigma^3 \, n^{3/2}} +
\\
\frac{\mathbb{E} [X_1^2]}{2} \frac{t^2}{\sigma^2 \, n} -
\frac{\mathbb{E} [X_1^2]}{2} \frac{m \, t^3}{\sigma^3 \, n^{3/2}} +
\frac{\mathbb{E} [X_1^2]}{4} \frac{m^2 \, t^4}{\sigma^4 \, n^2} +
O \left( \frac{t^3}{n^{3/2}} \right)
    \end{multlined}
\right]^n
    \]
\end{document}
```

**Addendum**
Regarding to your comment: if you for some (unknown) reason persist to use `align` environment, you can not get bracket around whole equation system but only at start of the first and end of the second line:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
&   \left[  
1 - \frac{m \, t}{\sigma \, \sqrt{n}} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{m^2 \, t^2}{\sigma^2 \, n} +
\frac{m \, t}{\sigma \, \sqrt{n}} - \frac{m^2 \, t^2}{\sigma^2 \, n} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{m^3 \, t^3}{\sigma^3 \, n^{3/2}} + \right.
\\
&\ \left.\frac{\mathbb{E} [X_1^2]}{2} \frac{t^2}{\sigma^2 \, n} -
\frac{\mathbb{E} [X_1^2]}{2} \frac{m \, t^3}{\sigma^3 \, n^{3/2}} +
\frac{\mathbb{E} [X_1^2]}{4} \frac{m^2 \, t^4}{\sigma^4 \, n^2} +
O \left( \frac{t^3}{n^{3/2}} \right)
    \right]^n
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

As I understood your question, you are after the first possibility.

Comment: Hello @Zarko, is it possible to write the left square bracket on the first line and the right square bracket on the second line?

Comment: I have also other equal signs before and after the square brackets, it's a long serie of equalities

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi put them into the multline and scale manually, no left/right

Comment: Hello @daleif can you write the code in order to understand better what you mean please?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi, no in `align`. IN it each line can be terminated by `\right.` or start by `left.` respectively. Well insted `left[` and `right]` you can write `\Biggl[` and `Biggr]` (where you should manually select appropriate bracket size (`\biggl` , `\Bigl`, etc), see addendum to answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can balance `\left[` with `\right.` and `\right]` with `\left.` but there is no guarantee that the brackets will be the same size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
\left[
1 - \frac{m \, t}{\sigma \, \sqrt{n}} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{m^2 \, t^2}{\sigma^2 \, n} + 
\frac{m \, t}{\sigma \, \sqrt{n}} - \frac{m^2 \, t^2}{\sigma^2 \, n} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{m^3 \, t^3}{\sigma^3 \, n^{3/2}} +
\right.
\\
\left.
\frac{\mathbb{E} [X_1^2]}{2} \frac{t^2}{\sigma^2 \, n} -
\frac{\mathbb{E} [X_1^2]}{2} \frac{m \, t^3}{\sigma^3 \, n^{3/2}} +
\frac{\mathbb{E} [X_1^2]}{4} \frac{m^2 \, t^4}{\sigma^4 \, n^2} +
O \left( \frac{t^3}{n^{3/2}} \right)
\right]^n
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

---

This uses `\vphantom` for force the brackets to be the same size.  The saveboxes are just to avoid entering the code twice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\newsavebox{\leftbox}
\newsavebox{\rightbox}

\begin{document}

\savebox{\leftbox}{$\displaystyle
1 - \frac{m \, t}{\sigma \, \sqrt{n}} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{m^2 \, t^2}{\sigma^2 \, n} + 
\frac{m \, t}{\sigma \, \sqrt{n}} - \frac{m^2 \, t^2}{\sigma^2 \, n} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{m^3 \, t^3}{\sigma^3 \, n^{3/2}} +$}

\savebox{\rightbox}{$\displaystyle
\frac{\mathbb{E} [X_1^2]}{2} \frac{t^2}{\sigma^2 \, n} -
\frac{\mathbb{E} [X_1^2]}{2} \frac{m \, t^3}{\sigma^3 \, n^{3/2}} +
\frac{\mathbb{E} [X_1^2]}{4} \frac{m^2 \, t^4}{\sigma^4 \, n^2} +
O \left( \frac{t^3}{n^{3/2}} \right)$}

\begin{multline}
\left[ \usebox\leftbox \vphantom{\usebox\rightbox} \right.
\\
\left. \usebox\rightbox \vphantom{\usebox\leftbox} \right]^n
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```